# Spring Security Maximum session timeout not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, session, thymeleaf

We have this

```
http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
```

and

```
http
    .logout()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout-gimli-user")).permitAll()
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "sessionid" /*, "sessdetail", "countfr"*/ );
```

and

```
 http
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .invalidSessionUrl("/login?invalidSession") //dokunma
    .maximumSessions(1) //dokunma
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true) //dokunma
    .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

in

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

And in **application.properties**, we have

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=3m
```

When a user tries to login, user puts **password** + **username**, then one time code is sent to user. After this, user needs to put this code and then can view pages.

But if user does not put that  code but only puts **username**+ **password**, and closes browser, logout is not working. Because logout is not invoked.

But timeout should work and kill after 3 minutes. Or tomcat should kill the session (because we deploy to external tomcat 9).

I tried this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450580/11369236

I added

```
@Bean
public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}
```

but still same.

I put

```
List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(authentication.getPrincipal(), false);
```

to

```
 @Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
```

in **public class CustomAuthenticationProviderWithRoles implements AuthenticationProvider {**

and tried lots of logins without one time code confirm and saw that, sessions are increasing.

But when i try with putting one time code, it does not allow because of **maxSessionsPreventsLogin**

like here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3078

Login page code:

```
 <form method="POST" th:action="@{/login}">
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="username"
                                            type="text">
   <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control password" name="password"
                                                type="password">

                            <button class="btn btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg"
                                            type="submit"
                                            value="Log In">LOGIN
                                    </button>
```

this is for 
login:

```
  http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

and **successhandler** does this for successfull login:

```
         response.sendRedirect("/otp");
```

Then, it sets the seconds which to count from for putting code. And sends another view to put code and which contains another form and submit button.

What can be best practice? For example user can close the page after putting user name password but session still remains. Despite there are timeouts.

I can use this and it solves it but I already session timeout in **application.properties**:

```
 public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response
    request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(11);
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193797/application-property-server-servlet-session-timeout-is-not-working-in-spring-b

And give response about your result

Comment: I already used it before and worked (see that part in question: `I can use this and it solves it but I already session timeout in application.properties:`) but I already set it in application.properties. Why do we need it again?

Comment: With `web.xml` configuration for session-out, it overwrite the configuration for session property of tomcat and use your configured property. So you should try it first

Comment: I said i tried it and it worked but it is not global.